# Unsubscribe interval after emission

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a code where I´m making an interval until a condition acomplish and then in the subscribe send back the result.

But since is an interval the subscription continue.

I was wondering if there´s any way to unsubscribe an Observable interval once emmit something

here the code

```
Subscription subscriber = Observable.interval(0, 5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .map(i -> eventHandler.getProcessedEvents())
                .filter(eventsProcessed -> eventsProcessed >= 10)
                .doOnNext(eventsProcessed -> eventHandler.initProcessedEvents())
                .doOnNext(eventsProcessed -> logger.info(null, "Total number of events processed:" + eventsProcessed))
                .subscribe(t -> resumeRequest(asyncResponse));
        new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscriber).awaitTerminalEvent(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
subscriber.unsubscribe();
```

For now as a hack I use a timer and then unsubscribe, but it´s bad!

Regards

Comment: What's your  condition?

Comment: The interval is asking for the number of events. And only go to onNext if we pass the filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `first` operator

```
Subscription subscriber = Observable.interval(0, 5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .map(i -> eventHandler.getProcessedEvents())
                .first(eventsProcessed -> eventsProcessed >= 10)
                .doOnNext(eventsProcessed -> eventHandler.initProcessedEvents())
                .doOnNext(eventsProcessed -> logger.info(null, "Total number of events processed:" + eventsProcessed))
                .subscribe(t -> resumeRequest(asyncResponse));
```

instead of the filter. This ensures that you only get a single emission if your condition is met. Note that you will get an exception if your condition interval Observable terminates without your condition being met.